# How do I see the pixel width/height of a layer in CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs5

I would like to be able to select a layer, and see the width/height of the selected layer in Photoshop CS5.  I'm sure there's an easy way to do this, but for the life of me, I can't find it.  I've tried putting it into transform mode, but it just shows 100% to let me adjust it percentagewise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-click in OS X) a layer in the *Layers* window, it will select the visible pixels in this layer.

[image]

Then, check your Information (*INFO*) window. As always, the width and height of the current selection will be displayed.

[image]

Comment: To change the units, use the tiny little button on the top right in the info window and navigate to "Palette Options"

Comment: To get the position (x,y) of the layer, see http://superuser.com/questions/318061/how-to-get-the-coordinates-for-a-selection-in-photoshop