# How to get the coordinates for a selection in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs5

I'm using Photoshop CS5 and I want to display information (size and position) of the current selection. In the information window I can see the size, but for position it "only" shows the coordinates from the cursor position.

I want to see the position (left-top corner) of the selection all the time. Like in Paint.Net. There you can see the attributes of your current selection in the status bar. Is this possible in photoshop?

My workaround so far is: Move the cursor to the desired start location, remember the coordinates (I have to write it down because the workflow can be interrupted) before making my selection.

Comment: another workaround is you can use the rulers and set them to the top left of the thing

Comment: this may be a workaround and probably still no good but ignore the arrows in this pic http://pe-images.s3.amazonaws.com/photo-effects/color-grid/first-guide.gif   see a little square where it says 0,0 near the top left, you can click and drag there and move to the top left of the image, and release. OTOH maybe that's not what you want 'cos you want the absolute position.. but you could use a ruler for that too without dragging.. so the ruler as it is, though i guess by sight is not as clear

Answer (score 23):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
to go to transform mode,
then the top left coordinate shows as X, Y in the information window.

Unfortunately, there is no way to see the coordinates
of the bottom right of the object, or selection for that matter.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for Smart Object layers.

Answer (score 8):

Fortunately, this is possible. Make sure that the Navigator/Info palette is open: Window>Info. Then on that palette use the Info tab and look at the x/y and w/h shown near the bottom.

Comment: Unfortunately X and Y show the cursor position, not the top left coordinates of the selection.

Comment: In the info window, it shows the cursor position, but also the width and height of the selection. So if you select from the top left corner to the point you're interested in the width and height represent the X and Y of the point you want.

Comment: While true, you can find the X Y position in the info panel at that "moment" you're mousing around on your document, this is useless if you want to see it without having to drag your mouse precisely back to the top-left corner of your selection. It should "stick" the values until the selection changes.

Comment: This works if you hit Ctrl+T to enter Free Transform mode. Then the X and Y values will show the actual object coordinates, not your cursor coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (I tested it on Photoshop CC, might not work on older versions):
create a new selection with the marquee tool - **don't release the mouse button yet!**

Now **hold spacebar, and the small popup now shows the top left coordinates** of the selection.
This does not work for existing selections, but at least it works for new selections.

tip: holding the spacebar while creating a selection allows you to move it.

Comment: This works. Just press spacebar before releasing selection tool and you get your X,Y coordinates

Answer (score 2):

At least with CS6 (I don't know if previous versions could),
you can hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to bring up a dot grid. 
Select top left for x1,y1 and bottom right for x2,y2.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the "Move (V)" tool.
2. Press and hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.
3. Move the cursor over the image and you will see the magenta lines with distances between the layers. If you have any layer with full image size you will get the coordinates you need.

[image]

Comment: Is this also available in CS6 or only in CC?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're looking for:

Use the Move tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>),
then touch on one of the handles. 
X & Y show up in the top left.

[image: coordinates of selected item]

Comment: Your answer is similar to the one posted last year but as you can see you didn't put much effort in your answer